# comparing int and short int using linq query in a CLR project doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq, clr

I have a CLR project with C# language, I'm debugging this project on a 64-bit windows 7. There is a linq query as:

```
var filteredList = myList.Where(t => t.NumOfDays >= calculationDays)
                            .OrderBy(t => t.NumOfDays ).FirstOrDefault();
```

note that NumOfDays has short type and calculationDays has int type.
unfortunately filteredList is always null, but when i use foreach query as:

```
foreach (var x in myList)
{
    if (x.NumOfDays >= calculationDays)
        filteredList.Add(x);
}

filteredList = filteredList.OrderBy(t => t.NumOfDays).FirstOrDefault();
```

it works truely. how can I fix this problem without converting data type of NumOfDays  to int?(I know when I convert the type, it will work, but I don't want to convert it, because this code works true on 32 bit operating system)

Comment: `myList.Where(t.NumOfDays >= calculationDays)` - did you mean `myList.Where(t => t.NumOfDays >= calculationDays)`?

Comment: It looks like you have a couple of errors in that first code sample and they are making it hard to understand what could be going wrong.  For instance the `Where` lambda isn't syntactically valid and the return type of `FirstOrDefault` is a single `myType` but you assigned it to a `List<myType>`.  Could you fix those up (perhaps just grab the code from your proje) and post it to the question?

Comment: I made a mistake when I wrote the question, but it is true in the project, I still have the problem